# Is it safe to access a method of C# from an unmanaged C library?

Tags: c#, c++, pointers, delegates, shared-libraries

I'm accessing a method of C# from C now. Below is some snippet of code in C#.

```
IntPtr pFunc = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate (
    new DelegateForMyMethodInCsharp (
        MyMethodInCsharp
    )
);

setFuncPtr(pFunc);
```

setFuncPtr() is a function of a C library to set the pointer of a C# method. After this code I can call the C# method in the C library whenever I want without any problems but I'm not sure if this is okay.

When using pointers for variables stored in heap in C#, the keyword 'fixed' must be used due to GC. Because the stack section of memory contains methods, it makes sense for me to write code like above. But because I haven't seen people write that way yet, I hope to hear your opinions.

This is a very simple question, but a very important question to me.
I don't want to write unsafe code.

Comment: Whether it is "safe" depends a great deal on the actual method.  We can't see it, only way you will feel better about it is when you actually try and test it.  You got this snippet wrong but you'll get a nice debugger warning about it.  When you actually try and test it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that the delegate instance is not garbage collected.

To do that, you can simply store it in a field, and make sure that field is rooted for as long as the unmanaged code hangs on to the pointer.

This is necessary because delegates store not just a pointer to a .Net method, but also state (the first argument; typically `this`).  To make a function pointer for that, the runtime must create a thunk that refers to this object, so that unmanaged code can get there from nothing but a function pointer.  This is bounded by the lifetime of the delegate instance.

For more information on the difference between delegates and function pointers, see [my blog](http://blog.slaks.net/2011/06/delegates-vs-function-pointers-part-3-c.html).

Comment: Thanks for setting me straight! I was stupid, didn't think about the instance of delegate at all! I just thought the code I wrote would pass the memory address directly to C, just like the variables in unsafe blocks. Thanks again!

Comment: BTW, you said "To do that, you can simply store it in a field, and make sure that field is rooted for as long as the unmanaged code hangs on to the pointer.", you sure doing this will fix the problem? I don't think this would help, because the reason why we use the keyword "fixed" in unsafe blocks is to prevent variables from not only being removed but also being 'moved' by GC. If I can't pin a delegate, I would fail to access from C even though the delegate instance is still alive.

Comment: PS. I read your articles, I liked them a lot!

Comment: @Jenix: Don't worry; the runtime will handle that for you.